# avoid broken design web page when user zoom in or out

Tags: html, css

how to avoid destruction design web page when the user zoom in or out,
when i look into others website, their design is not broken when i zoom out or zoom in
this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all.css">
<title>Personal Page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></head>
<body  >
<table border="0"width="100%" height="100">
<tr>
<td align="left" width="25%"> <img src="compas.png" width="150" height="150" ></td>
<td align="right"  valign="top" width="40%"  ><img src="scrol.png" width="120" height="120"><p id="text1">Home</p></td>
<td align="right"  valign="top"><img src="scrol.png" width="120" height="120"><p id="text2">About</p></td>
<td align="right"  valign="top"><img src="scrol.png" width="120" height="120"><p id="text3">Photos</p></td>
<td align="right"  valign="top"><img src="scrol.png" width="120" height="120"><p id="text4">Hobbies</p></td>
<td align="right"  valign="top"><img src="scrol.png" width="120" height="120"><p id="text5">Qbook</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" ><font face="old english text mt"><font size="6"><b>Personal Page</b></font></td>
<td colspan="5"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the css

```
body { 
background: url('background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
} 
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

#text1
{
    position:absolute;    
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    left:790px;
    top:40px;
}
#text2
{
    position:absolute;    
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    left:914px;
    top:40px;
}
#text3
{
    position:absolute;    
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    left:1029px;
    top:40px;
}
#text4
{
    position:absolute;    
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    left:1141px;
    top:40px;
}
#text5
{
    position:absolute;    
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    left:1264px;
    top:37px;
}
```

what i have to add and what i have to change, please guide me

Comment: Have you tried using Bootstrap? http://getbootstrap.com/ This library is designed to handle broken page. You need to getaway with TABLE and switch to DIV element instead.

Comment: The thing you're looking for is called [Responsive Web Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design). Several frameworks make it easy to do. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/) is one of those.

Comment: ty for the commend, so i did read about bootsrap, but i still no idea how to use it, maybe u guys can offer me some webs for learn about bootstrap.thankx

Comment: @venray bootstrap are so easy to use. load the libraries, and call the classes on your elements. U can load the libraries via cdn or u can dowload them on bootstrap website

Answer (score 1):

The **simple solution** for your problem is **using pixel** insted of percentage **to provide width**. you are using percentage style to provide width to  **table and td** tag which is not recommended in web page designing. The page is look broken because *the width as per percentage is fixed for any system while zooming also but the text and other alignment are depending on pixel style while getting zoom.* 
  **So please take a fixed pixel width to the complete page and than subdivide them into required parts (*in pixel style*)**

as an example for the above code in am using 1380px as default width because general system screen have 1380px(you may those different):-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all.css">
<title>Personal Page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></head>
<body  >
<table border="0" width="1380px" align="center" height="100">
<tr>
<td align="left" width="write pixel"> <img src="compas.png" width="150" height="150" ></td>
<td align="right"  valign="top" width="40%"  ><img src="scrol.png" width="120" height="120"><p id="text1">Home</p></td>
<td align="right"  valign="top"><img src="scrol.png" width="120" height="120"><p id="text2">About</p></td>
<td align="right"  valign="top"><img src="scrol.png" width="120" height="120"><p id="text3">Photos</p></td>
<td align="right"  valign="top"><img src="scrol.png" width="120" height="120"><p id="text4">Hobbies</p></td>
<td align="right"  valign="top"><img src="scrol.png" width="120" height="120"><p id="text5">Qbook</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" ><font face="old english text mt"><font size="6"><b>Personal Page</b></font></td>
<td colspan="5"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

*The css file is fine(no changes required), zoom the above coded html page it will not look broken.

Comment: ty before sir,and yeah, i changed the percentage to pixel already, but when i zoom out, it's like become smaller but to the left, when i saw another people webs, they are just like smaller but on the middle, how is that posibble ?

Comment: we can use a div tag as parent tag to whole page and use align="center" attribute in css file for that div. i think that will solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using body width in percentage, make sure that you assign a max-width on body tag and this will enable proper page zoom in and zoom out feature.